# How to retrieve an image file from a backend to a Worklight application

Tags: sql, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created a Worklight application and I need to get some images from a backend back to the application. How can I do that? Also, can I get video or mp3 from the backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you mean...:

1. Do you have images on a file server that you simply want to display on the app? Then since the backend is yours, you already know the URL and you can simply have that URL be placed in a `HREF` tag in your HTML...
2. If you need to RETRIEVE the image, save it locally in the device and then display it, you will need as Marko suggested to base64 encode the file and send it back.
   Your adapter's procedure will send the filename of the image to retrieve. On the backend there will be a servlet that will take it, encode it and send it back as the response to your adapter's request.

> Also, can I get video or mp3 from the backend?

Sure. This is agnostic to the application...

Answer (score 0):

**You could**

1. Send the pictures as base64
2. If the pictures are hosted on a web server, only get the URL and send that to the client

Comment: yes,I think I can get the url by using the SQLAdapter,but then how to  get the pictures with the url?